# Botón que abre web introducida en un maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Visual Studio y tengo un botón que necesito que abra una web,pero quiero que esta pueda ser elegida por el usuario así que puse una zona con un maskedTextBox y un botón ¿Como podría hacer para que al escribir en ese maskedTextBox una url y darle al botón de guardar se establezca esa web en el botón de abrir web?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear algún método que cuando haga click donde dices, te guarde esa página en propiedades de la aplicación.
Y que el boton de abrir web despues abra la web guardada en ajustes.

Se accede a la derecha de visual studio, donde tienes la lista de archivos y formularios, dando doble click a Properties, y en la pestaña Settings, creas una variable, por ejemplo WebElegida. Es importante crear la variable antes.

Para guardarla en ajustes:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.WebElegida = "www.tuwebElegida.com";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Para cargar la página:

```
Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.WebElegida);
```